# Mongodb terminates when it runs out of memory

Tags: mongodb, docker, limit, ram

I have the following configuration:

- a host machine that runs three docker containers:

  - Mongodb
  - Redis
  - A program using the previous two containers to store data

Both Redis and Mongodb are used to store huge amounts of data. I know Redis needs to keep all its data in RAM and I am fine with this. Unfortunately, what happens is that Mongo starts taking up a lot of RAM and as soon as the host RAM is full (we're talking about 32GB here), either Mongo or Redis crashes.

I have read the following previous questions about this:

1. [Limit MongoDB RAM Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718165/limit-mongodb-ram-usage): apparently most RAM is used up by the WiredTiger cache
2. [MongoDB limit memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365224/mongodb-limit-memory): here apparently the problem was log data
3. [Limit the RAM memory usage in MongoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86109/limit-the-ram-memory-usage-in-mongodb): here they suggest to limit mongo's memory so that it uses a smaller amount of memory for its cache/logs/data
4. [MongoDB using too much memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148395/mongodb-using-too-much-memory): here they say it's WiredTiger caching system which tends to use as much RAM as possible to provide faster access. They also state `it's completely okay to limit the WiredTiger cache size, since it handles I/O operations pretty efficiently`
5. [Is there any option to limit mongodb memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage): caching again, they also add `MongoDB uses the LRU (Least Recently Used) cache algorithm to determine which "pages" to release, you will find some more information in these two questions`
6. [MongoDB index/RAM relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811299/mongodb-index-ram-relationship): quote: `MongoDB keeps what it can of the indexes in RAM. They'll be swaped out on an LRU basis. You'll often see documentation that suggests you should keep your "working set" in memory: if the portions of index you're actually accessing fit in memory, you'll be fine.`
7. [how to release the caching which is used by Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468873/how-to-release-the-caching-which-is-used-by-mongodb/4482465): same answer as in 5.

Now what I appear to understand from all these answers is that:

1. For faster access it would be better for Mongo to fit all indices in RAM. However, in my case, I am fine with indices partially residing on disk as I have a quite fast SSD.
2. RAM is mostly used for caching by Mongo.

Considering this, I was expecting Mongo to try and use as much RAM space as possible but being able to function also with few RAM space and fetching most things from disk. However, I limited Mongo Docker container's memory (to 8GB for instance), by using `--memory` and `--memory-swap`, but instead of fetching stuff from disk, Mongo just crashed as soon as it ran out of memory.

How can I force Mongo to use only the available memory and to fetch from disk everything that does not fit into memory?

Comment: This is really a better fit on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) as it's about database server software, not application code.

Comment: Ok, I am fine with an admin moving it. Should I do something about this?

Comment: (though most questions I linked are from StackOverflow)

Comment: Some of those questions pre-date those two sites. There's ~1500+ questions on each of those two relating to MongoDB. If it's about setup, I'd say the Server Fault site. If it's about tuning, DBA.

Comment: Is there something I can/should do in order for it to be moved?

Comment: Easiest to just shut it down here and re-post there. Hope you can find the answer! This looks like a tricky problem.

Comment: Which do you think would be most appropriate between DBA and SF?

Comment: I'd try DBA first since this isn't a simple "how to install" type question.

Comment: Good research efforts, but the question itself is quite vague. Storage config and actual error message  are critical missing bits. Ideally, if you can share Dockerfile and simplest mgenerate which reproduces the problem. Thre is a special note in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB for mongodb running in a container that don't have access to whole memory.

Comment: MongoDB could use a lot of memory if it make a `collscan` on a request. Are you sure you have an indexe on all your requests ?

Comment: @AlexBlex I do really think your comment fixed my issue. I am still doing some tests but if you feel like turning it into an answer there is a very high chance I'll accept it!

Comment: @SimoneBronzini, glad my comment gave you a clue, but it hardly qualify for a full answer. If you have found a solution, you can answer the question yourself providing enough details for other to resolve similar problems. It seems it draw some attention, and I am sure people will appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexBlex's comment I solved my issue. Apparently the problem was that Docker limited the container's RAM to `8GB` but the wiredTiger storage engine was still trying to use up `50% - 1GB` of the total system RAM for it's cache (which in my case would have been `15 GB`).

Capping wiredTiger's cache size by using [this configuration option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) to a value less than what Docker was allocating solved the problem.

Comment: How did you get the configuration option into the docker container?

Comment: Ah, you can use a command line option https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#wiredtiger-options - `--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB`

Comment: Hi @rjmunro  What if the storage engine is MMAPv1? there is no option to config its cache size.

Comment: Hey @Simone we are running MongoDB in docker having in issue with memory. when I see a free -m it uses lots of memory more than 8gb so I assume it does related to this issue?